# Repeat the content of a String

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to replicate a given String without any changes *n* amount of times but can`t seem to do it properly.

Here`s my most promising attempt, which failed.

```
espaco = (" ");

tartaruga = ("T");

chegada = ("|");

line_T = ( tartaruga + 70*(espaco) + chegada);
```

Comment: `String.join("", Collections.nCopies(70, espaco))` P.S. I would love to see your less promising attempts.

Comment: You can't use `*` on `String`s in Java. You can use `Collections#nCopies`. With Java 11 there is `String#repeat`.

Comment: Porquê os parêntesis todos?

Comment: Please research prior to asking questions. That question was asked multiple times already :) Read [ask], thanks.

Comment: @Zabuza Java 11? What's the future like??

Comment: @Luis You can experiment with it here if you like: http://jdk.java.net/11/

Comment: @Zabuza nice. But that's still a work in progress. The latest (at this time) stable released version is 9. The most used JDK is still 8. Most programmers I know haven't even migrated to 9 yet, much less the 11. :P